# Is there a standard format for HMAC in cookies?

Tags: http, cookies, http-headers, hmac

Given a **cookie** `x` with a **value** `1` ..

```
Set-Cookie: x=1
```

.. a **Message Authentication Code** (MAC) `y` is added, in this case with a `|` delimiter.

```
Set-Cookie: x=1|y
```

How should the data, `1`, and the MAC, `y`, be separated? Above, a delimiter is used, but this approach fails if the data could contain the delimiter. I considered using JSON,

```json
{ "data": 1, "mac": "y" }
```

Which I believe would then have to be URL-encoded?

```
Set-Cookie: x=%7B%22x%22%3A1%2C%22mac%22%3A%22y%22%7D
```

**Is there a standard** for the format of cookie values that contain MACs?

The calculation of the MAC, `y`, should be irrelevant to this question. If necessary, please assume `y` is calculated using [OpenSSL HMAC SHA-256](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/HMAC.html).

Answer (score 2):

If we start with the HTTP standard for cookies, we see that the [syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.1) doesn't have any special support for message signatures. What *is* supported is arbitrary metadata via attributes using the `extension-av` syntax. So you could do something like:

```
Set-Cookie: x=1;myhmac=y
```

Or, as used in [this article](https://medium.com/@jonmbake/the-why-and-how-of-mac-http-cookies-7fbb2debe47b), simply `x=1;y`. In practice this is likely to work fine, but in theory it runs into the issue of collision with other metadata uses (what if the client applies some other meaning to `myhmac`?). This is a common problem with any system for extending a standard.

If the HMAC isn't HTTP-level metadata, then it must be stored in the content of the cookie. Your suggestion of using a data structure containing the value and the signature and then encoding it is consistent with the standard:

> To maximize compatibility with user agents, servers that wish to
> store arbitrary data in a cookie-value SHOULD encode that data, for
> example, using Base64.

Base64 is certainly preferable to URL encoding, and since it has a restricted character set you could simply Base64 the value itself, and then be sure that your chosen delimiter (let's say `.`) won't collide with the value. So instead of encoding a JSON object you could simply do:

```
Set-Cookie: x=Base64(1).Base64(y)
```

In my experience this is probably the most common approach: using Base64 for the value and signature, separated by a delimiter of your choice. To pick an example that I'm familiar with, this is how Django handles [message signing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signing/#protecting-complex-data-structures), including in cookies, using `:` as a delimiter.

A more general approach would be to use [JSON Web Signatures](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515) (part of [JSON Web Tokens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token)), a proposed standard for handling signatures that can be used in headers. This approach is similar to the last one but includes metadata (like the algorithm used). The compact syntax is:

> BASE64URL(UTF8(JWS Protected Header)) || '.' ||
> BASE64URL(JWS Payload) || '.' ||
> BASE64URL(JWS Signature)

JWT libraries are probably available in all languages. Note, though, that the generality and complexity of JWTs poses potential security risks, and many would [warn you away](https://groups.google.com/g/django-developers/c/6oS9R2GwO4k/m/Rep92xfsAwAJ).